# Offset from each nth cell with dynamic anchor cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have hard times understanding Excel formula for Offset.

How I can start my range from 1 in this case, so it is 1, 3, 5 etc. At the moment it goes 3, 5, 7.

[image]

Also my offset formula should be dynamic. I mean I have tried something like `=OFFSET($W$619;(ROW()-630)*2;0)` but in this case it is not dynamic, so if I add rows on top, row number is not anymore 630 and formula is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close with your solution. The dynamic can be achieved when you combine the `OFFSET` function with the `ROWS` function, which counts the number of rows between two cell references.

You also have to subtract 2 since you do not want to step down two rows in the first cell.

The final formula is:

```
=OFFSET($W$619;ROWS($W$619:W619)*2-2;)
```

[image: OFFSET function to dynamically reference the n-th element in a range in Excel]

Comment: Thank you! It works! I guess it should be `=OFFSET($W$619;ROWS($W$619:W619)*2-2;0)`

Comment: @Tabisamsa Yes - you can write it like that as well. I just omitted the last zero, which works fine.